# Break from the tradition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Something much harder than calculating the last digit. What is the last three digit of ${1998^8}$. How know you can't merely multiply the last digit in seek of a sequence. But you may multiply 998 part. But still it is too hard. I guess there is a new way of solving this type of problem I have never known of.

Comment: $1998 \equiv -2 \pmod{1000}$

Comment: This can be solved in almost exactly the same way as you would calculate the last digit.

Comment: Yes, a new way you've never known, the *negative numbers* :)

Answer (score 4):

$$
(1998)^8 \equiv (-2)^8 = \boxed{256} \pmod{1000}.
$$

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: ${1998}^8$/1000 will have the same remainder as ${(-2)}^8$/1000.??

Comment: Why do we use negative mod? Trying to make 1998 into 10000

Comment: @user11355 Yes, $1998 / 1000$ will have the same remainder as $(-2)^8 / 1000$.  That is, if you define the remainder to always be positive, so that the remainder of (say) $-9$ mod $30$ is $21$.

Comment: @user11355 But what I really mean when I write $\equiv$ is not so much "have the same remainder mod $1000$"; it is closer to "differ by a multiple of $1000$".

Comment: But why do you use -2 to compare to 1998?

Comment: @user11355 Because $-2$ and $1998$ differ by a multiple of $1000$.  Look up [modular arithmetic](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic).